# Access to webapp from a different machine

Tags: iptables

So i have three virtual machines (virtual box).

1. One is the router/firewall. It's running snort + snortsam .
2. This machines runs a webapp in tomcat
3. From this machine I'm trynig to access the webapp i machine 2.

Machines 1 and 2 are connected through an internal network. Same for machines 1 and 3.

I want to access machine 2 webapp from machine 3, but I'm not being able to do that.

So far I have this iptables configuration on machine 1:

```
iptables -A forward -p tcp -d <machine_2_ip> --dport http -j ACCEPT
iptables -A forward -p tcp -d <machine_2_ip> --dport https -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

What I'm getting on machine 1 with tcpdump is:

```
ARP, Request who-has <machine_2_ip> tell <machine_3_ip>, length 46
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you for the attention.

**EDIT v2**
[image]

**EDIT v3**

So the solution was to add the defalt gw's on both M1 and M3 and it worked, but not always.
Sometimes my iptables look like this:
[image]

And it doesnt work that way. Only works when it shows: destination -> 192.136.200.3 instead of cpe-192...
Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Are you certain it's a `iptables` issue?  Is VM1 a pre-configured router distro (such as `zeroshell` or `pfSense`)?  Or is it a standard unix or linux distro used as a router?  If it's the latter, have you enabled IP Forwarding on it?

Comment: I think it's a iptables issue or routing issue. Yes , I've enabled ipforwarding. I'm using CentOS 6.0 as a router/firewall.

Comment: Flush your `iptables` on all three VMs to remove it from the equation.  As this is a private network, then you could add your network configuration to the question, which will help people understand your setup.

Comment: I've flushed iptables too.

Comment: Nice diagram ;-) And good thinking with the `tcpdump`.  M3 believes M2 is on it's local network (hence the ARP request) when it actually isn't.  M2 doesn't see this request (as there's a router in the way) and therefore does nothing.  Check your subnet masks.

Comment: I updated the picture a bit. Were these masks you were talking about?

Comment: They look fine.  Do you have similar masks on both interfaces of M1? Also, have you set up a default gateway of M1's IP address on M3 and M2? Can you confirm that the internal VirtualBox network are different for each subnet? For example, `internal1` and `internal2`.

Comment: BTW: Those two networks shown on the chart are actual, assigned IP addresses—you shouldn't use them for your testing. Use RFC1918 space instead. They're assigned to Centro de Informatica da Universidade de Coimbra in Portugal.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I had to set up the defalt gw's like garethTheRed said. It's working now. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I've updated the question again, because it's not always working.

Answer (score 1):

That ARP request means that M3 incorrectly thinks that M2 is on the same subnet, instead of behind the gateway M1.

Almost certainly, it is one of two things:

1. Subnet mask on (at least) M3 is wrong.
2. You've configured something nonsensical; e.g., you've used the same subnet on both the M1/M3 and the M1/M2 networks.

That's weird, because your chart shows something that should work, but I'm pretty certain the chart doesn't reflect what you've actually configured. Confirm by checking, on all three (virtual) boxes `ip addr ls` and `ip route ls`.